# The gradient of a max function at a differentiable point

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent

I suppose to:

Calculate the direction of steepest descent for the function
$$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2+\max(0,(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2-4)$$
at the point $x=(0,-2)$.

What I did:

Since the direction of steepest descent is $-\nabla f(x^k)$, I try to find the gradient of $f(x)$.

But at the point $x=(0,-2)$, $(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2-4=0$, equal to the first element in max function, so I don't know how to determine the gradient of this max function at that point.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not differentiable at $(0,-2)$. Since $f$ is convex, it has a subdifferential.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. Does that mean the direction should be an interval?

Comment: I'm not sure of the context. Is the context convex or non differential analysis?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I think so. It's in the non-smooth case of nonlinear-optimization.

Comment: Then the steepest descent is the negative of the nearest point to the generalised gradient.

Comment: Oh, Yes. Thank you. It should be $[-1,0]^T$

Comment: Yes, that is correct, $\partial f((0,0)) = \operatorname{co} \{ (1,1), (1,-1) \} $.